# I cant figure out why this SQL Query is not working, am I not allowed to use subqueries in this case?

Tags: mysql, subquery

I am trying to update the amount of the row with max(amount)

```
$this -> mysqli->query("
    UPDATE `table`
    SET `amount` = amount - '".$diff."'
    WHERE `s_ID` = '".$id."'
    AND `amount` = (SELECT MAX(amount) FROM table)
") ;
```

Comment: Just a note: If your `$diff` and `$id` variables are coming from users, this method of constructing the query is vulnerable to injection attacks. Also, with double quotes, PHP will look for variables inside the string, so you don't need to use concatenation. i.e. `"...SET amount = amount - $diff WHERE..."` will work.

Comment: thanks JYelton, no those are internal values, but anyway every user input is escaped with `mysqli -> real_escape_string($_GET[$key])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you are not. You can't update from a table using the same table in a subquery.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

See the end of this page (before the comments):

> Currently, you cannot update a table and select from the same table in a subquery.

If you decide to break this into two separate queries, one to get the max value and another to do the update, please remember to do so inside a transaction, and use Select ... for update; so mysql will lock the records you'll be updating, otherwise, some nasty issues can arise from concurrency (if it applies to your particular case).